# Exact images and texts embedding size is not showing in keras/tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

Note: it's not an issue I just want to know the reason.

I am trying to implement keras clip model where the model uses text encoder and vision encoder for text and image embeddings generation. when I try to print the shape of compiled images and texts then it just shows the output shape and not the exact number of images or texts it has pre-processed like `(None, 256)`. while there are about 3000+ images and texts in my dataset.

```
def call(self, features, training=False):
    with tf.device("/gpu:0"):
        caption_embeddings = text_encoder(features["caption"], training=training)
        print(caption_embeddings.shape)
    with tf.device("/gpu:1"):
        image_embeddings = vision_encoder(features["image"], training=training)
        print(image_embeddings.shape)
    return caption_embeddings, image_embeddings
```

Any tensorflow or keras developer will better understand this question. Full code of my colab file is [HERE](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1xG1HcneqwmxKNcHnklcyPQdPCKIxc3Mp?usp=sharing) the original implementation is [HERE](https://keras.io/examples/nlp/nl_image_search/)

Comment: when you post colab link, please check that the dataset is available to everybody, not on your drive disk...

Comment: Ok Sir I will try next time, I did same as you provided in the answer. When I define the `run_eagerly=True` in `fit()` then it says run_eagerly unknown and when I define it in `compile()` then another error generates like `ResourceExhaustedError: Exception encountered when calling "bert"`. Colab notebook with the available dataset is in this [LINK](https://colab.research.google.com/github/keras-team/keras-io/blob/master/examples/nlp/ipynb/nl_image_search.ipynbhttps://colab.research.google.com/github/keras-team/keras-io/blob/master/examples/nlp/ipynb/nl_image_search.ipynb) which anyone can run.

Comment: `ResourceExhaustedError` means that tf can't allocate enough memory, try with the second option that I've posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`call` is called before training to build the graph, thus the first dimension is not known.

When you compile your model, you can do something like this:

```
model.fit(..., run_eagerly=True)
```

and you will see that print that you expect, however the training will be very  slow... instead, you can use `tf.print(tf.shape(caption_embeddings))` to do it in graph mode

Comment: Thanks for your excellent answer. My batch size was 256 when I changed it to 20 then it started running.